# jQuery addClass on scroll is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, scroll

Okay, I'm trying to apply a CSS Style to an `<img>` tag that does not have any `class` or `id` assigned to it. Here is my code:

===CSS===

```
.tgll-navi { //begin custom class for navi bar
 .navi-left { //.navi-left
  float:right; 
  text-align:center; 
  } // end .navi-left
  img { // img
  max-height:269px !important; 
  max-width:524px !important; 
  height:75%; 
  width:75%; 
  padding:7px; 
  background-color:white; 
  border-style:solid; 
  border-color:black; 
  border-width:4px; 
} // end img
.scale { // scale
  max-width:174px !important; 
  max-height:89px !important; 
  height:25%; 
  width:25%; 
  padding:3px; 
  background-color:grey; 
  border-style:solid; 
  border-color:black; 
  border-width:2px; 
}// end scale; 
}// end tgll-navi class
```

=== jQuery Code ===

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop(); 
if (scroll >= 5) {
  $('img[src="http://gourmetlunchladies.com/new/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/image3355.png"]').addClass(".scale");
} else {
    $('img[src="http://gourmetlunchladies.com/new/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/image3355.png"]').removeClass(".scale");
}
});
```

I am not getting any errors in the JavaScript console.log
if I add alert ('Message'); after the .addClass I get the alert popup.
I removed alert to see if the class was applied but the class does not get applied.

Working inside WordPress with DMS2 everything is updated to the latest version

Know me I probably forgot a period or semi-colon

Brent Higgs

Answer (score 2):

Remove the "." from your addClass functions, you don't need it ;

```
...addClass(".scale")
```

becomes

```
...addClass("scale")
```

Answer (score 1):

> You are adding `.scale` classname. You should add `scale` classname

```
$('img[src="whatever"]').addClass("scale");

$('img[src="whatever"]').removeClass("scale");
```